# Treatment x time boxplots in sas

Tags: sas, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot in SAS that displays 2 treatments over 5 periods in the same chart.   I can make it do one or the other but not both.   Code is below.

```
proc boxplot data=data;
id treatment;
plot pred1*sample;
run;
```

also tried

```
proc boxplot data=data;
plot (pred1 sample)*treatment;
run;
```

no luck either way.   Any ideas?  Seems like this should be straightforward.

Thanks

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're going for as the final result.  Can you post an image of what you'd like it to look like, or a little better description?  Do you want two boxes side by side, one based on pred1 and one based on sample?

Comment: For a variable I have 2 treatments for the study.  Within each treatment I have 5 sample times.  There is significant treatment?*time interaction and I would like a box plot that would show the lsmeans of each treatment at each sample time in the study.

Comment: You're going to get more useful answers if you provide a short example of your data and a picture of what you want it to look like.  Graph questions in particular are very hard to answer usefully without both.

Comment: Unfortuneately I can't make the chart to show you.   In the chart below you have red and blue for pred and sample.   What I am trying to do would be have two boxes such as your red and blue for each treatment.   Axis for the chart would then be sample (time) and the value of the ls mean for each treatment at the time it was sampled

Answer (score 3):

`proc sgplot` can likely do this, if I understand you properly and if you have the right version of SAS (9.3+ or maybe 9.4+, I'm not sure which).

I'm assuming you want two boxes, one for pred and one for sample.  Here's a simple example:

```
data treatments;
  call streaminit(7);
  do treatment=1 to 2;
    do period=1 to 5;
      pred1 = treatment+period+rand('normal')*4;
      sample = treatment+period+rand('normal')*5;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;


proc sgplot data=treatments;
  hbox pred1/ category=treatment legendlabel='Prediction' discreteoffset=.2 boxwidth=0.2;
  hbox sample/category=treatment legendlabel='Sample' boxwidth=0.2;
run;
```

There I set them next to each other using the `discreteoffset` (moving the bar a bit) and shrink the bar to match the offset.

[image: First Example]

You could also use `group` to do this, using a vertical dataset (ie, one 'value' variable with an indicator that identifies which result group they're in).

```
data treat_vert;
  set treatments;
  group='Prediction';
  value=pred1;
  output;
  group='Sample';
  value=sample;
  output;
run;
 proc sgplot data=treat_vert;
   hbox value/category=treatment group=group;
 run;
```

[image: Second Example using GROUP]

Both options have a lot of flexibility in terms of labelling/etc. if you want to go that route.